# How to get the number of events in a regular interval of time in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I'm having dataframe as shown below.
In the data frame we are representing the events occurred on every sec.

```
Time     events_occured
1           2
2           3
3           7
4           4
5           6
6           3
7           86
8           26
9           7
10          26
.           .
.           .
.           .
996         56
997         26
998         97 
999         58
1000        34
```

Now I need to get the cumulative occurrences of events in every 5 secs.
As in first 5 seconds 22 events occurred, from 6 to 10 secs 148 events occurred and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [647]: df['cumulative'] = df.events_occured.groupby(df.index // 5).cumsum()

In [648]: df
Out[648]: 
   Time  events_occured  cumulative
0     1               2           2
1     2               3           5
2     3               7          12
3     4               4          16
4     5               6          22
5     6               3           3
6     7              86          89
7     8              26         115
8     9               7         122
9    10              26         148
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are missing values ​​of Time using `df.index` could produce errors in the logic so use `df['Time']`.
It also works if time starts at any value N and if there are missing values ​​greater than N

```
GROUP_SIZE = 5
df['cumulative'] = df.events_occured\
    .groupby(df['Time'].sub(df['Time'].min()) // GROUP_SIZE).cumsum()
print(df)


   Time  events_occured  cumulative
0     1               2           2
1     2               3           5
2     3               7          12
3     4               4          16
4     5               6          22
5     6               3           3
6     7              86          89
7     8              26         115
8     9               7         122
9    10              26         148
```